# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Set' (T_STRING) on line 53

Tags: php

I have an error in my PHP but I can't find it

```
if( ! function_exists('set_bulk_product_quantity') ) {
function set_bulk_product_quantity() {
    $bulk_qty = WC()->session->get( 'bulk_qty' );
    if( empty($bulk_qty) )
        $bulk_qty = '0;

   $label_name    = __('Set Products minimal Bulk Quantity ', 'woocommerce');     // LINE 53
    $submit_button = __('Set quantity', 'woocommerce');
    $reset_button  = __('Reset', 'woocommerce');
    $style         = 'style="max-width:80px;text-align:right"';
```

Comment: You missed the closing quote on the line before.

Comment: Using a decent IDE would show up the missing quotes and save asking questions like these.

Comment: Thanks! I was focused on the line 53! What a stupid!

Comment: I encourage you to use a better IDE, I use eclipse PDT. It has it's quirks but it's free.  And does code completion and basic syntax checking.

Comment: @NigelRen - just saw your comment, what do you use?

Comment: I've used Eclipse for a long time, but I also do some C++.  I use the Docker and XML plugins as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the

```
$bulk_qty = '0;
```

Line to

```
$bulk_qty = '0';
```

Comment: Thanks! I was focused on the line 53! What a stupid!

Answer (score 0):

Seriously!

Change the line `$bulk_qty = '0;` with `$bulk_qty = '0';`

You missed a closing '

Comment: Thanks! I was focused on the line 53! What a stupid!

Comment: Nah, it's a common mistake. There are lots of meme for that "programmers horror" ;)

Comment: A good IDE will cure this issue.  I use Eclipse (with PDT) which is not to say it's good. but it works and is free. I could get something paid for but .. blah.

Comment: Give a shot to "Visual Studio Code". There are lots of plugins for PHP which can make your life a lot easier. Have a look: http://www.accella.net/knowledgebase/debugging-php-with-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0):

```
  if( empty($bulk_qty) )
        $bulk_qty = '0;
```

You should modify it:

```
  if( empty($bulk_qty) )
        $bulk_qty = '0';
```